# Where is the definition of `load?(tz, Crystal::System::Time.zone_sources)`?

Tags: crystal-lang

I could not find the definition of `Time::Location.load?(string, Array(String)` from https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/7fb783f7afec0a199d6f22ef78aae0f45517068a/src/time/location.cr#L343

(Crystal 0.25.0)

Is it a "magic" function outside of the .cr source files?

Comment: [Here?](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/7fb783f7afec0a199d6f22ef78aae0f45517068a/src/time/location/loader.cr#L15)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had looked in that file. I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: Generally, all methods are defined in some Crystal source file. In some rare occasions the methods might not actually be *implemented*  there, but AFAIK that's only a couple of core methods on primitive types.

Comment: @WPeN2Ic850EU you should post that as an answer